# Winsock Error 1013- Permission Denied

Tags: c, sockets, permission-denied, winsock2

I'm trying to run the simple program below using C:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    printf("Initialising Winsock...\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        getchar();
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Connect to remote server
    iResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof (server));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(s);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This is basically a C program that create a socket and makes a connection to Google. (I'm just following the tutorial: http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial as I'm completly new to socket programming).

Now my program outputs:

```
Initialising Winsock...
Initialised.
Socket Created.
Connect function failed with error: 10013
```

After some research I found that this means that this is a permissions denied error.
I tried looking for some fixes such as running Visual Studio Express as Administrator and running these commands on my command prompt:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log hit
```

and restart my computer but it still does not work.

Its worth mentioning when I ran the 2nd command: netsh int ip reset reset.log hit I got the following error message:

```
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.
There's no user specified settings to be reset.
```

Even though I was running the command prompt as admin.

I also temporarily deactivated my Kaspersky Internet Security but still no fix. I am completely new to C and socket programming.

Comment: you should zero sockaddr_in server struct before using it

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean (I'm new to C)? What code should I write?

Comment: memset( server, 0, sizeof server);

Comment: I tried: "memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);" before the  "server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");", but that doesn't solve anything! server alone gives me a compile time error!

Comment: I am very sorry. Did I say something wrong? Why are you shouting?

Comment: I'm not shouting lmao. How would you even know if I'm shouting or not lol?

Comment: based on usage of exclamation mark 0x21. It serves as an indication of higher volume.

Comment: Most probably google is not letting you connect to its port.

Comment: He would have received connection refused then, but 10013 is WSAEACCESS and [these](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-common-causes-of-socket-error-10013.htm) are common causes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and I can use it to connect to some other machine. I made a little modification since I do not have a machine running a HTTP server at hand right now. Therefore I used www.google.com:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
remoteHost = gethostbyname("www.google.com");   // get IP of www.google.com
server.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)remoteHost->h_addr);  // inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(80);
```

The output of your application is:

```
Initialising Winsock...
Initialised.
Socket created.
Connected
```

So basically your implementation is correct.

This means that there is some other gremlin around! The [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of error 10013 is:

```
WSAEACCES
10013 (0x271D)
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

This can be caused by antivirus or firewall software. Therefore try to disable your firewall and anti virus and run your application again.

If that works try to find the firewall/anti virus setting(s) which may block your application from connecting. This can be quite an ordeal (I know what I'm talking about)...

Comment: Thanks, but as i said in the question, I have already disabled my Kaspersky but to no avail

Comment: Well I know from first hand experience that especially Kaspersky kinda sticks to protecting you (even if turned off)...

Comment: So how exactly do I turn it off

Comment: ONe thing I would try is to turn off automatic startup after booting. Furthermore you can add rules to allow your program to do things (but since your program changes during development you propably need a new rule after each build). A final brutal way is to deinstall it. Additionally make sure the Windows firewall is disabled.